# In Android OS or Java, what's the difference between a character sequence and a string?

Tags: android, string, types

For the API (Android SDK API version 8) functions whose definitions list character sequence parameters, I can feed the function String instead. Best part is that they work the same way, no hassle, no warnings.

Is there a difference between the two types? And more importantly, is there an inherent danger if I send the function a String instead of a character sequence???

Thanks for any clarifications!!! :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a difference between the two types?

**Yes. `String` is a class, and `CharSequence` is an interface.** If a method accepts a `CharSequence`, it only requires the argument to implement the methods in the interface, which gives a greater flexibility, than if it would accept only a `String`.

The following API classes implement `CharSequence`: `CharBuffer`, `Segment`, **`String`**, `StringBuffer`, `StringBuilder`. That is, a `String` *is a* `CharSequence`, and can thus be passed to a method that accepts a `CharSequence`.

> And more importantly, is there an inherent danger if I send the function a String instead of a character sequence???

**No**, there is no danger. `String` properly implements `CharSequence`, and that's all the method will require to function properly.

Comment: Also, String is final (http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), so it cannot be extended.